# C# how to change menuStrip hover color?

Tags: c#, colors, menustrip

Good day people, I want to change the color of a menu item on my menuStrip when I hover above it. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: no, it's not. I want to change the main item hover color, and there is nothing about it in that question

Comment: no, the text background

Comment: So that isn't about it? I think that one is also changing the item's background color on hover?

Comment: After writing my answer, I saw the duplicate. It is very similar, although my answer uses stupider names :D. You can change the colours of course.

Comment: Have you analyzed my question and this what you've linked? Theese two questions are really not duplicate

Comment: They may not be the exact same question, however they both link you to the `ProfessionalColorTable` class, which is what you need.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I didn't knew how to access or refer to the colors which I wanted to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using the normal `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events. You need to directly override the menu rendering. You can do something like this, using the `MenuStrip` class:

```
private class renderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
    public renderer() : base(new cols()) {}
}

private class cols : ProfessionalColorTable {
    public override Color MenuItemSelected {
        // when the menu is selected
        get { return Color.Blue; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd {
        get { return Color.White; }
    }
}
```

And just in case you're interested, this is what happens when you use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events. (Inside the `MouseEnter` event, it was making the `BackgroundColor` green, however that was not been called):

[image: Only the leave event was been called.]

Comment: exactly what I've been looking for, thank you kindly sir.

Comment: Glad I could help. Note you can do a lot more with the `ProfessionalColorTable` class. See this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColorTable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where are the `Enter` and `Leave` methods you're talking about? Why the background should've been to green?

Comment: The `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event handlers on most controls. I was just explaining how these could not work to change `BackgroundColor`, because menus are awkward. I would show you my sample code I played around with but I've deleted it now.

Comment: you can find the enter and leave events in the events section, but that doesn't work as odixon said

Comment: I know about the events, but I couldn't understand your visual example where you said **(The enter method should've made the background green)**

Comment: Just slightly incorrect wording, I will change if it _offends_ you :)

Comment: `Color MenuItemSelected` will just change the color of the MenuStrip **sub-items** only.